# Step by step writing answers

Tags: support, editing, community-wiki

#### Shalom Rav LeOhave Toratecha

A double question:

1. Mostly I write answers step by step, for many reasons, new ideas, correction after comments that show me errors... But the main reason is that I can not write without interruptions. **The problem is that for saving the answer, the only way I know is to publish**. Publishing when you know that it is not finished is not a good think. ***Is there an alternative solution?*** (except for the *first draft* that is automatically saved)
2. In the right bottom of the frame we see a little square entitled ***community Wiki*** what is it?

Comment: Google docs. Saves all your papers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. One option might be to publish, then delete your post. When you are ready to proceed, undelete it, edit and republish. Would be good to hear confirmation from a moderator before you try it with a lot of content though :-> (users with more than 10k reputation will be able to see your post but not to vote on it - so maybe good to put a quick note at the beginning e.g., "*post being edited - will be undeleted when ready*")
2. Community wikis are described [here on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) (a good resource for any general question on Stack Exchange)

> Community wiki posts work by partly transferring ownership of the post
>   from the original author to the community. They make the post easier
>   to edit and maintain by a wider group of users, but they do not
>   contribute to any user's reputation.

Comment: pinging @MonicaCellio - would you mind checking my proposed option 1 above? many thanks

Comment: Proposal 1 sounds good to me fwiw. And that comment didn't ping Monica Cellio: see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: After Maasse your solution to delete-undelete post is the better for me.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of posting and then deleting, you can save your answer in a file on your computer, and continue editing it there. Then, when you're ready, paste it here and post.

[Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackedit/iiooodelglhkcpgbajoejffhijaclcdg) is a markdown editor app for Google Chrome that will save your document in the browser.

Comment: It is not easy because the format of posts here are not as office or libre office or google docs.

Comment: I seek an intra-stack exchange solution as the draft automatically saved.

Comment: You can still paste in the markdown code. Or use a plaintext editor such as Notepad.

Comment: Good point. Or use a Markdown editor. I use iAWriter on Mac and iOS for instance

Comment: @mbloch know you markdown editor online free for non mac??

Comment: @kouty If you use Chrome, there is one in the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: Niflo! you can complete perhaps the answer and it will be a quasi perfect answer.

Comment: @kouty Added it in.